# Get checkbox for Boolean field in attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, boolean

I have a dataset with a lot of Boolean fields.
In the attribute table, they are represented with text (either `true` oder `false`). If I click into the cell, I get the checkbox I also get in the attribute form.

I want to be able to

- Quickly switch state
- Make it easier to see their given state ("white box" or "black/checked box" vs. two words about the same length)

Is there a way to always view the checkbox instead of the text in the attribute table?

When I set widget type to checkbox, display settings can only be "True/False" or "Stored Values", which both give me the same output.

Comment: Note to self: I do enjoy having high tier people making my question look picture perfect, but I'd rather have an answer on an ugly question than no answer on a beautiful question...